# Texture format for cellular automata in OpenGL ES 2.0

Tags: optimization, opengl-es, low-level, gpgpu, cellular-automata

I need some quick advice.

I would like to simulate a cellular automata (from [A Simple, Efficient Method
for Realistic Animation of Clouds](http://nis-ei.eng.hokudai.ac.jp/~doba/papers/sig00_cloud.pdf)) on the GPU. However, I am limited to OpenGL ES 2.0 shaders (in WebGL) which does not support any bitwise operations.

Since every cell in this cellular automata represents a boolean value, storing 1 bit per cell would have been the ideal. So what is the most efficient way of representing this data in OpenGL's texture formats? Are there any tricks or should I just stick with a straight-forward RGBA texture?

**EDIT:** Here's my thoughts so far...

At the moment I'm thinking of going with either plain GL_RGBA8, GL_RGBA4 or GL_RGB5_A1:

- Possibly I could pick GL_RGBA8, and try to extract the original bits using floating point ops. E.g. `x*255.0` gives an approximate integer value. However, extracting the individual bits is a bit of a pain (i.e. dividing by 2 and rounding a couple times). Also I'm wary of precision problems.
- If I pick GL_RGBA4, I could store 1.0 or 0.0 per component, but then I could probably also try the same trick as before with GL_RGBA8. In this case, it's only `x*15.0`. Not sure if it would be faster or not seeing as there should be fewer ops to extract the bits but less information per texture read.
- Using GL_RGB5_A1 I could try and see if I can pack my cells together with some additional information like a color per voxel where the alpha channel stores the 1 bit cell state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a second texture and use it as a lookup table.  In each 256x256 block of the texture you can represent one boolean operation where the inputs are represented by the row/column and the output is the texture value.  Actually in each RGBA texture you can represent **four** boolean operations per 256x256 region.  Beware texture compression and MIP maps, though!